# How to Parse UserAgent in Javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, windows-xp, agent

I need to use Javascript to get the Operating System of a user.  After some research through the forms I found that I need to use navigator.userAgent to get the information that I require.  When I use this a string is returned similiar to:
5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36

What I need specifically is to get the Operating System version (so in the above example Windows NT 6.1) and based on that do some code similar to:

```
if(operatingSystem = 'Windows NT 5.1'){
//do code
}
```

So basically I need to parse the user agent string and if the user is on windows XP (Windows NT 5.1) then do some code.  I am having difficulty parsing the string though to get just the operating system. I also cant use navigator.oscpu since that will only work for Firefox browsers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: You don't want your example to be 'Windows NT 6.1'?

Comment: No.  Sorry for the confusion, my current OS is Win7 which is why the string I gave shows Windows NT 6.1 but I specifically need to grab Windows XP which is 5.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
if(/Windows NT 5\.1/.test(navigator.userAgent)){
    // do code
}
```

Comment: Seems to work just the way I need it to.  Thank you very much for the prompt response.